# Import data from dated text files and skip if none exists

Tags: excel, vba, import

I need to get data from flat files into a spreadsheet for trend analysis of items killing disc space.

My goal is to import drive folder size data generated by each server every month.

Each file is named as the server name and yy-MM date tag.

My raw data worksheet has a column for each file's data.

I want to import the file's contents into the rows below each column heading, as well as skipping imports when the file name matching the column data is not found.

For example, the flat file for September is named "server 18-09". It contains 10 rows of numbers as below. Each row is data of the defined folder/path:

File name: "server1 18-09"

File Data contents:

> 17.6689338684082
>     25932849152
>     5604237
>     763363328
>     0
>     884641998
>     13426067872
>     16316400460
>     1798912358
>     14219095504

My spreadsheet looks like this:
[image: server data excel.xlsm image]

Comment: There's a good chance that this could be done without VBA as well, but I'm better with VBA than plain Excel. You might be able to import the contents of a folder if you store all your files in the same place. Like Data>Get Data>From File>From Folder but I can't try it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this, works fine:

```
Sub t()

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "\\corp.com\rootDisc Usage\"
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

For Z = 0 To 12 'variable for next month column range after each prior     column range completes.
For s = 0 To 12 'Counter for limiting looping and start the next server to process.
y = (s * 13) 'Increments after initial loop to the next server file name for processing.

        If fso.FileExists(strPath & Range("MMYY").Offset(y, Z).Value) =     True Then

      If Range("MMYY").Offset(y + 1, Z) = "" Then
     'Locates next server file to process by referencing the file name in the  correct range and prevents
 'processing and overwriting data in the spreadsheet if the data is already populated.

        Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath & Range("MMYY").Offset(y, Z).Value, ForReading)
        'opens the correct file matching the file name in the offset specified range cell, in read only mode
        i = (1)
          Do
           Range("MMYY").Offset(y + i, Z) = ts.ReadLine
           i = i + 1
        Loop Until ts.AtEndOfStream
       ts.Close
       End If

Else
    'file doesn't exist

End If

Next
 'exits data write loop
    Next
 'exits column processing loop
     Z = (Z + 1)
     'increments active column offset to the next month column.
Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The only problem I have is error 62 when a blank file exists. Trying to figure out how to add a Do WHILE NOT ts.AtEndOfStream and keep the looping working.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the input past end of file if a flat file was blank by putting a line of code in to bypass my write loop if a file had no content this way:
            If ts.AtEndOfStream = False Then

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking into the [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object). It's quite helpful when looking through folders/files on your computer and has the ability to [read files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/186118/how-to-use-filesystemobject-with-visual-basic). Start with something like this:

(Code is untested and is given as is, just an example. It will not work with copy/paste!)

```
Dim fso as Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim ts as TextStream
if (fso.FileExists("Path\to\file.txt") then     'Also could be a range variable's value
    'Get file contents
    set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("Path\to\file.txt")
    'Loop while not end of file
    Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
        'Set a cell's value to the read line
        Range(something).value = ts.ReadLine
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot seadoggie01
I am trying your method now and making some progress, just having to figure out how to do the reading each line of the text file(s) and storing the string values in my cell ranges. 

The ts variable defined as TextStream, didn't work, I ended up defining it as TextRange2 (I'm blindly 'trial and error'ing it due to my lack of knowledge). So far it gets to a compile error for 'Method or data member not found" at loop, where the ts.AtEndOfStream is, have a hunch I need to tell it where to put each line (I'm still confused on it right now)

Comment: Here is the code the way it is (with the above mentioned error):Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim ts As TextRange2
    If fso.FileExists("\\server\path\Server Disc Usage" & Range("c134").Value) Then



    'Get file contents
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("\\server:\path\Server Disc Usage" & Range("c134").Value)
    'Loop while not end of file
    Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
        'Set a cell's value to the read line
        Range("C:135").Value = ts.ReadLine
    Loop
End If